# How to cope with a observable collection binded datagrid with manual update

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, observablecollection

I have a datagrid

```
<DataGrid Name="dtgFeatures" Height="100" Margin="10" ColumnWidth="*" CanUserAddRows="True" MouseLeftButtonUp="DtgFeatures_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
```

which is binded to an observable collection

```
ObservableCollection<CfgPartPrograms> obcCfgPartPrograms = new ObservableCollection<CfgPartPrograms>();
```

with

```
[Serializable]
public class CfgPartPrograms
{
    public CfgPartPrograms() { }
    public string Group{ get; set;}
    public string Description{ get; set;}
    public string Filename{ get; set;}<------set with openfiledialog
    public string Notes{ get; set;}
}
```

Now since I want to be able to insert the filename with an openfileDialog I have add this code:

```
private void DtgFeatures_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    int column = (sender as DataGrid).CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex;
    if ( column == 2)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofdPP = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (ofdPP.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            if (obcCfgPartPrograms.Count == 0)
                obcCfgPartPrograms.Add(new CfgPartPrograms() { Filename = ofdPP.FileName });
            else
                obcCfgPartPrograms[selectedIndex].Filename = ofdPP.FileName;
            dtgFeatures.ItemsSource = null;
            dtgFeatures.ItemsSource = obcCfgPartPrograms;
        }
    }
```

the problem is that when I set the filename the observable collection has not been updated yet.
I'll explain that with images:

[image]

So I have added aaaa and bbb now I want to force the filename with the code above but when I do that the bind action has not been done yet on the observable collection so that aaaa and bbbb are not present.

[image]

In short how to tell the binded datagrid to update the binding??

Thanks in advance
Patrick

Answer (score 1):

Your CfgPartPrograms class should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and raise the PropertyChanged event whenever a data bound property is set to a new value: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

```
[Serializable]
public class CfgPartPrograms : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public CfgPartPrograms() { }

    public string Group { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    private string _fileName;

    public string Filename
    {
        get { return _fileName; }
        set { _fileName = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I think that your idea is correct ands that is the solution but it doesn't work. First I think that the observable collection has to be updated not when filename changes but when the other members do. So I have put the notify property changed on the group. But apart from that after having entered the data in the datagrid and having pressed the ENTER key, the Set code of the Group property is not hit.

Comment: In short manual changes on the datagrid do not reflect on the observable collection

Comment: The source property will be set when you step away from the row by default. You don't need to explicitly call the CommitEdit method unless you want to commit the changes by cell: http://blog.scottlogic.com/2009/01/21/wpf-datagrid-committing-changes-cell-by-cell.html. This is another issue than your original one though. Please remember to accept the answer if your issue has been solved.

Comment: I found the solution thanx

Answer (score 0):

I found it [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ef320d19-f407-4d11-83cd-32b2cbe06287/binding-a-datatable-to-a-datagrid-using-twoway-mode?forum=wpf): I was missing the

```
dtgFeatures.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, true);
```

command